# Plot a histogram through all the columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data that has several columns in it.

```
Country    Weight    # of food/day  ....
---------------------------------------------
USA         180         4
China       190         12
USA         150         2
Canada      300         10
```

I want to create (separate) histogram for each of the columns such that histogram_1 shows the distribution of 'Country', histogram_2 shows the distribution of 'Weight', etc.

I'm currently using panda to upload and manipulate the data.

Is the easy way to do this is by doing like this?

```
for column in df:
    plt.hist(column)
    plt.show()
```

Please forgive me if my idea sounds so stupid.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want separate plots, or all in one window?

Comment: @Joe Separate. My plan is to have # of histograms == # of columns (features)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a histogram for non-numeric or discrete values is not unambiguous. Often the question is "how many item of each unique kind are there?". This can be achieved through `.value_counts`. Since you say *"# of histograms == # of columns (features)"*, we might create one subplot per column.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Countries" : ["USA", "Mexico", "Canada", "USA", "Mexico"],
                   "Weight" : [180, 120, 100, 120, 130],
                   "Food" : [2,2,2,4,2]})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df.columns), figsize=(10,5))
for col, ax in zip(df, axes):
    df[col].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(ax=ax, title=col)

plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your implementation is actually better than my current one. I do need value_count() because, without it, I got like a verse small and widespread plot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can use this instead of for loop, histograms for all numeric columns will be generated!

```
df.hist(bins=10, figsize=(25, 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the histograms in different windows, then you can do in this way:

```
df.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].plot.bar()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I was on the right path; it was just slow because I have a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Countries" : ["USA", "Mexico", "Canada", "USA", "Mexico"],
                   "Weight" : [200, 150, 190, 60, 40],
                   "Food" : [2,6,4,4,6]})

for col in df.columns:
    plt.hist(df[col])
    plt.xlabel(col)
    plt.show()
```